# Merge Data from Multiple Remote SQL Databases into One SQL Master DB

Tags: sql, database, merge, constraints

Well, I'm sure this question has been asked before but I'm yet to find a single solid answer to it. I'm in the process of creating a solution that involves remote offices uploading data to one master db via  web service.
Basically, each office will have a windows service that runs every 1hr or so, picks up any new data into a dataset, connects to the server via http, and uploads the dataset. The server then imports the data and all is well. In theory it should work. Right.

Not really, so each office has a unique OfficeID, given to it by the server so as to keep them unique on the server. At first I thought I'd cracked it till I realised the problem with auto-increment PKs. You see, all the remote offices already have existing data and all their tables all have Auto-Increment PK's and all associated constraints. Root/Parent Tables that have the OfficeID have no problem since it is already unique, the problem lies with the foreign keys since when they'll reach the server, they'll have a NewID and so the relationship with the child will lost.

At the moment I have only 2 solutions.

1. Remove all auto-increment and unique PK constraints on the server db and use the OfficeID to filter out duplicate foreign 'keys'. or...
2. When importing the dataset, keep track of each row and it's associated parent using stuff like Scope_Identity etc so that each child row is associated with the correct parent row.

Option 1 is looking much easier to implement since its less work for me, but I wonder about sql's performance and also data integrity will be a problem since constraints cannot be enforced. Option 2 will keep things in check but Gosh the amount of code needed is mind boggling.

Are there any other options that I'm not considering? and if I only have the 2 above, which is the lesser of two evils.

Thanks
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use GUIDs as your primary keys. It's not 100% foolproof (99. and a fairly large number of nines percent), and there is a performance penalty, but it is the easiest way of doing this while remaining sane.

Comment: I'm already using GUIDs in each table for updates/modifications, since I know there is now way GUIDs can be duplicated even across all them databases. This is probably the route I'll use. On the server i'll just have columns like ProductGUID etc that will ensure that each child row knows it's correct parent without any room for doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Can you include the Office id in the table and have a composite primary key?  If not I would probably go with @tdammers suggestion of using a GUID.

Comment: I'm actually using a bit of both. All tables have OfficeID, and in combination with the exiting (previously auto-number PK), now form a composite key. I'm using this in addition to GUIDs to just keep everything nice and tidy. The reason I'm keeping the old PK columns is that the server db already has reports that expect the db to remain the same, only that all reports will now be grouped by office.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the PK constrainst is going to lead to disaster at some point.  I'd vote for option 2 - it's more work, but you'll have a more robust and maintainable solution at the end of it.  It does mean that the office databases won't match the master any more - they'll need updated too...

Comment: I have to remove them, the more I thought about it the more I realised I had no choice. If you have more than one level depth of child rows, keeping track of new rows etc becomes a nightmare. Using Guids is the route I'll take, no chance of duplicates on the server and so they can go in as is.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, including the Office ID in all the primary keys in the 'central' database will solve the primary key issues while maintaining integrity AND allow you to report by office.

But NOTE that you DON'T NEED TO ALTER the 'source' database structure if you can add in the Office ID as part of the data transfer method. Just add the office ID to every table in the 'central' database and include it in the primary key (getting rid of the auto increment/identity definitions from the 'source' schema) and tag each record with office ID as it gets transferred. This is the approach we use in [sql-hub](http://sql-hub) and applies across most RDMSs (MySQL, MS SQL etc).

IMPORTANTLY though any joins etc done on the 'central' database will have to be changed to add in the Office ID or you will get erroneous and unwanted [CROSS JOINS](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-cartesian-joins.htm).